# Import dates in google SpreadSheets with importxml

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets

I am trying to copy the data on this page (http://www.progsport.com/icehockey/) in my google spreadsheet.

I need all the data in the table and I want to separate them. I managed to copy the column of the matches with the instruction:
= IMPORTXML (B7; "// td / pre"), where B7 is the url.

Now I want to copy the rest but I do not know because they are special classes. I did several tests and I do not get it. How can I find that data, for example the number of (Photo1) of all the rows?
In other cells there are images. I want to copy the links of the images to treat them later. How do I copy those links in my document? (Photo2)

Thank you so much for your time.

[image: Photo 1]

[image: Photo 2]

Comment: Was my answer useful for you? If you have issues for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. Such information helps me to study. Also I think that it helps other users to know the situation as an information.

Answer (score 1):

How about this answer? I put `http://www.progsport.com/icehockey/` to "A1" for this sample.

### For Q1 :

```
=IMPORTXML(A1, "//tr[contains(@class, 'f')]")
```

#### Result :

[image]

Columns C - F are images. So data cannot be retrieved as the text data.

### For Q2 :

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("http://www.progsport.com/" & IMPORTXML(A1, "//tr[@class='f2']//img[@class='im']/@src"))
```

#### Result :

[image]

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.